# Accessing variable from a data class in custom RecyclerView. Adapter

Tags: android-recyclerview

For Android App programming in Kotlin, I created a data class, AlphabetData, Kotlin file with a variable as below:

```
package com.example.wordapp.model
```

class AlphabetData {

```
val alphabetList: List<Char> = ('A'..'Z').toList()
```

}

In custom RecyclerView.Adapter class, I want to access the variable alphabetList. For example, After importing AlphabetData class in custom RecyclerView.Adapter, I wrote under
`override fun getItemCount(): Int {return AlphabetData.alphabetList.size`.
I am getting error that the variable alphabetList is not recognized. Do I  have to create a function to access that variable?

I am very new to programming. Would appreciate feedback

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to access your alphabetList with class name you have dectlare it under the companion object like this :

```
companion object{
    val alphabetList: List<Char> = ('A'..'Z').toList()

}
```